# How can I cheaply fix these blue blotches on my LCD monitor?

Tags: lcd

When my grandparents used this dusty Samsung SyncMaster 913v LCD monitor yesterday, the monitor was working normally.

This morning my grandparents first wiped just the screen with a micro-fibre cloth with hand soap water, then wiped it again with a 2nd micro-fibre cloth rinsed with tap water, then a third time with a 3rd dry micro-fibre cloth. Then they saw these vertical colored stripes and blue blotches.

[image]

1. Are we correct to assume that [the liquid seeped in, "killing" pixels](http://www.aotearoapeoplesnetwork.org/content/how-destroy-pc-monitor-one-easy-lesson)?
2. Please see this question's title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix these vertical colored stripes on my LCD monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/1508847/how-can-i-fix-these-vertical-colored-stripes-on-my-lcd-monitor)

Comment: @MrEthernet No it doesn't. I posted that question on a different quandary with the same screen.

Comment: Please don't post the same question 3 times. While there are *slight* differences between the posts they are as near as makes no difference "how do I fix this thing?"

Comment: If they've gone away, the issue is likely resolved, however, for future reference, when cleaning any non-sealed electronic screen (monitors, TVs, etc.), there should never be enough liquid on the screen that the liquid can form droplets and run down the screen.  A microfiber cloth only needs to be damp, but not wet, to clean a screen, with a 3:1 5% vinegar to water solution generally working the best.

Comment: @JW0914 They haven't "gone away".

Comment: @JW0914 That statement pre-dates the first para. Fixed.

Comment: Saving an ancient CRT monitor with multiple issues is probably not worth your time.  $100 will get you a modern monitor ( make sure you get one with appropriate inputs, like VGA / D-Sub ).  You might also ask at nearby businesses / schools / recycling centers if there are any spares.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal The blue is likely from one of two sources, either it's seeped in between one or more of the polarized filters before and/or after the liquid crystals, resulting in only blue light passing through or it's from damage to a portion of the liquid crystal circuitry... to determine which, the monitor would need to be disassembled and the front and rear of the LCD screen visually inspected since you likely can't separate the sandwich that makes up the LCD without damaging it. If the money is available, a ~23" 1080p Acer monitor can be purchased for ~$100 online.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal Since the two scenarios above would seem the likeliest, it's not as simple as evaporating the water out due to the impurities in water.  If it's water that's seeped in between the [polarized filters](https://cdn.hswstatic.com/gif/lcd-screen.gif), even if evaporated out, it will leave minerals behind that will likely result in that portion of the screen never properly displaying as the minerals will scatter the light that's intended to go through horizontal and vertical polarized filters.  If it's water damage to the liquid crystal circuity, the damage is likely permanent.

Answer (score 3):

From the number of your posts, I understand that this monitor dating from 2005 is
of importance to your grandparents, but I don't know how practical it would be
to save it, if at all possible. This could take several days, even if successful.
From the fact that your grandparents decided to give it such a good clean,
it is possible that the quality of the screen was already degrading with time.

The problem is whether there is only water damage, or if there is also
soap damage, so whether getting the water out will be enough.
If you would still wish to try, here are some ideas.

If your parents have a ventilator, they could place the monitor in a warm and dry
place and set the ventilator to blow on the screen for several hours or even
one day.

Another possibility, if they have a small container or cupboard big enough to
contain the monitor, is to place a large quantity of (cheap) rice on the bottom,
place the monitor face-down on the rice, then seal the container for a few days.
Adding desiccant bags, like iFixIt's
[Thirsty Bag](https://www.ifixit.com/News/thirsty-bags),
can also help.

For the future, I suggest that alcohol wipes for cleaning eyeglasses would do the
cleaning job pretty well, but it's important to avoid pressing strongly
on the glass screen.

Comment: You don't need a container for the "rice method". Just put the monitor and the rice in a large garbage bag and seal it with adhesive tape.

Comment: @Robert A large garbage bag... so... a container?

Comment: @T.J.L.: A large garbage bag can be called a container for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave it, do nothing and hope it goes away as it dries out in normal use.

I washed my MacBook Pro screen with too much soapy water (I used the liquid soap normally used for washing dishes) and got a big stain where it leaked inside the LCD panel.  A Lenovo laptop I have lost more than half the screen due to moving from hot humid environment (by the pool) into a cold, dry Air Conditioned environment (inside hotel) causing condensation to form in the LCD panel within seconds of going inside.

In both cases over some *weeks* the stains shrank and both have worked without further problems for years now.  The Lenovo is completely fine while the MacBook has only slight marks around the edges of where the stain was - presumably from the remains of the soap that in retrospect I obviously shouldn't have used.

While this is obviously anecdotal things can improve naturally.

Whether trying to speed the process via heat or desiccants would help or hinder I don't know but as long as it isn't actually *wet* and it is safe to use then using it will mean the screen getting a certain amount of heat to assist the drying process anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could place the monitor and a dehumidifier in a closet. If this is as other suggested, water climbing the LCD monitor via capillary action, drying out the physical space in which the monitor sits should draw the water out of the LCD.

This will not work if the damage is permanent.